# Convert the First page of a PDF to JPG or PNG - PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, image-conversion

I'm unable to configure ImageMagick on MacOSX(10.9.4) for PHP. Is there any other way to do the conversion i.e., without ImageMagick or is there any simple way to do so? I just need to convert the first page of my pdf file to either .jpg or .png.

Comment: We have no idea what the issue is you are having. Hence impossible to help you.

Comment: I just wanna know whether the above conversion is only possible through ImageMagick? Do we have no other means to do so? @PeeHaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is shell code that does the conversion without using ImageMagick:

```
pdftops -f 1 -l 1 -paper letter input.pdf - | gs -q -sDEVICE=png16m -r300x300 -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sOutputFile=output.png -
```

`pdftops` is part of the poppler utilities.  `gs` is ghostscript.  If you don't have access to `pdftops`, it is possible to use Adobe's `acroread` instead.

There are many options that can be used to adjust the output to your preferences.  For example, the `-r300x300` option shown above produces a bitmap with a resolution of 300 dpi.  That can be adjusted to any higher or lower resolution that `gs` supports.  Also, the driver above, `png16m`, produces 24-bit color PNG.  For gray, use `pnggray`.  For monochrome, use `pngmono`.  For jpeg output, use `jpeg`.  `gs` also has drivers for many other bitmap formats.

#### Debugging

If the above doesn't work at first, I would suggest trying it at the command line first and, only when that is successful, then put it into PHP.  Further, I would suggest breaking it into parts

Part 1:  Check to see that this creates a (large) postscript file:

```
pdftops -f 1 -l 1 -paper letter input.pdf - >output.ps
```

Part 2:  If the above successfully creates a postscript file, then try:

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=png16m -r300x300 -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sOutputFile=output.png - <output.ps
```

This should create `output.png`.  If either part gives errors, please quote the exact error.

Comment: I tried calling the command through exec() of php. But there is no response. I think it doesn't recognise "gs". How do i sort it out?

Comment: @DhiwaTdG I added some thoughts on debugging to the answer.  Let me know what happens.